# Collisions does not work

Tags: gazebo-9

[image: Gazebo Answers logo]

Hello,

I am trying to define a custom model for my robot. I have modeled it in Fusion 360, then exported as OBJ and I have written SDF file. When I import the model, I can see the visual and collision meshes line up perfectly. However, when I run the simulation, my model falls through the ground plane. There are no contact points detected. I also tried to convert the collision mesh to STL and use it instead as I have found and issue on a bitbucket claiming OBJ files do not work as collision meshes.

What do I miss in my configuration? I assume it is a silly mistake. My model is available here: https://files.honzamrazek.cz/models.zip

EDIT: I have looked into ~/.gazebo/server-{num}/default.log and there are following lines:

```
(1569313534 985992523) [Wrn] [ModelDatabase.cc:340] Getting models from[http://models.gazebosim.org/]. This may take a few seconds.
(1569313600 130413970) [Wrn] [SystemPaths.cc:459] File or path does not exist [""] [model://universalModule/meshes/bodyA.stl]
(1569313600 130600551) [Err] [MeshShape.cc:66] No mesh specified
(1569313600 131292799) [Wrn] [SystemPaths.cc:459] File or path does not exist [""] [model://universalModule/meshes/bodyB.stl]
(1569313600 131651177) [Err] [MeshShape.cc:66] No mesh specified
(1569313600 132344317) [Wrn] [SystemPaths.cc:459] File or path does not exist [""] [model://universalModule/meshes/shoeA.stl]
(1569313600 132547141) [Err] [MeshShape.cc:66] No mesh specified
(1569313600 132956421) [Wrn] [SystemPaths.cc:459] File or path does not exist [""] [model://universalModule/meshes/shoeB.stl]
```

So the problem is with using the model:// path specifier. How to use it properly?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.gazebosim.org/question/23825/collisions-does-not-work/) by [yaqwsx](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/16621/yaqwsx/) on Gazebo Answers with karma: 13 on 2019-09-24

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Gazebo Answers logo]

Try adding the path to your `universalModule` folder to the system variable `GAZEBO_MODEL_PATH`.

---

Originally posted by [kumpakri](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/6511/kumpakri/) with karma: 755 on 2019-09-26

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [yaqwsx](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/16621/yaqwsx/) on 2019-09-27**:
Thank you - it helped (actually, I have to add the path to the models' database).

I don't understand how paths work in Gazebo. I would like to specify all paths relative the SDF file so when I put my models in a repository anyone can run the simulation easily. I consider specifying the GAZEBO_MODEL_PATH as extremely inconvenient for the user. What is the proper way to distribute my model database and simulation to users?

**Comment by [kumpakri](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/6511/kumpakri/) on 2019-09-27**:
This seems as a good question for a new post. I simply include my models in a package and add the path to the GAZEBO_MODEL_PATH in launch files.

```
<env name="GAZEBO_MODEL_PATH" value="$(find robot_gazebo)/models:${GAZEBO_MODEL_PATH}"/>
```